# Get Local Timestamp not working Android

Tags: android, date, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to get the timestamp from a date. But i'm trying to getting the Local timestamp, but event setting the Timezone, i'm still getting the timestamp in UTC.

This is my Code:

```
public static Long dateToTimestamp(String dateFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Log.e("AQM", TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
        try {
            Date date = formatter.parse(dateFormat);
            return date.getTime() / 1000;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return Long.parseLong("0");
        }
    }
```

This is the Logs:

```
04-19 23:11:01.751 4593-4593/br.com.vitorvillar.aquariummanager E/AQM: 20/04/2016 23:10
04-19 23:11:01.751 4593-4593/br.com.vitorvillar.aquariummanager E/AQM: Brasilia Standard Time
04-19 23:11:01.751 4593-4593/br.com.vitorvillar.aquariummanager E/AQM: Brasilia Standard Time
04-19 23:11:01.761 4593-4593/br.com.vitorvillar.aquariummanager E/AQM: 1461204600
```

The date and the TimeZone is OK, the Timezone is `Brasilia Standard Time`, but the Timestamp still 3 hours ahead from here. When i convert in a online converter the Date is `21/04/2016 02:10`

So, someone know what i can do?

Comment: Don't set a timezone to your `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I am assuming that input string is in UTC. If that assumption is correct, I suggest you to set "UTC" in formatter. Try following

```
public static Long dateToTimestamp(String dateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Log.e("AQM", TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateFormat);
        Log.e("AQM", date.toString());
        return date.getTime() / 1000;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return Long.parseLong("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: The input date is not UTC, is local Time